# ArrayList string searching

Tags: c#, search, arraylist

As part of my University course, we've got to use ArrayLists to create a record booking system, and I want to include a way of searching for the surname of the Booking, is there a way to do this in C#?
The ArrayList contains the variable "surname", and at the moment I have this

```
private void search()
{
    string term;
    term = searchBox.Text;
    foreach (string surname in dataList)
        if (surname == term){
```

and that's where I'm stuck. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where are you stuck, I mean, what is not working? Do you get an error?

Comment: Please consider at least providing function that ends at the end of statement not half way through it... And see if you coding guidelines are ok with use of {} after `foreach` as recommended in most other C# guidelines...

Comment: I would suggest you think about what the Search() method needs to return - is it another collection or just a single list item?  In your code fragment you are returning nothing - the method's return type is 'void'.  Does that get you any further forward?

Comment: I believe its not working because of case sensitivity, your should use some thing like  if (surname.ToLower() == term.ToLower())

Comment: Assuming your ArrayList contains just a string of surnames then the IndexOf solution will work - though most of the time I'd expect the surname to be on a `customer` object or whatnot

Comment: You should really be using `List` rather than `ArrayList` as well, so that it's always clear what the type of the elements are.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to use `IndexOf` and check if the index is not negative:

```
int pos = dataList.IndexOf(surname);
if (pos >= 0) {
    // It's there - do whatever you need to do...
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1... But I think using `Any` would be more appropriate as OP seem not to like curly braces :).

Comment: What about case sensitivity? Not what the OP stated clearly, but it could be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ArrayList datalist = new ArrayList 
            {
                "asd",
                "surname",
                "dfg"
            };
        Console.WriteLine(datalist.IndexOf("surname") != -1 ? "Found" : "Not found");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```